# How to constraint clang-tidy to FIX-IT only in the source file and not all headers

Tags: clang-tidy

Does anyone know if its possible to have clang-tidy -fix to NOT make modifications in header files. (either at all or headers only in the current directory)

I'd like to clean selected source files first before attempting to work on the hundred of global headers

Answer (score 2):

Use `clang-tidy` with the `--header-filter` option to select only those header files you want processed.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, I also worked out I could do something like this                      
     -line-filter='[{"name":"File.Cpp"},{"name":"File.h"}]'